# how can i make the loop create new objects as my results?

Tags: r, loops, output, plyr

I am new in R and I am learning how to make loops. I wonder if what I am trying to do with this loop makes sense:

```
require(plyr)

year = c("1993", "2009")

for (i in 1:2) {

  temp <- subset(census.long,trt=="RIL" & dbh > 50 & date==year[i])

  tab.res[year[i]] <- ddply(.data=temp, .(spcode), 
                 .fun=summarise, 
                 volume = sum(volume))
}
```

I would like to have two results as new data.frames/matrix/whatever: (1) tab.res[1993] and (2) tab.res[2009], but I guess this is nit the way to go with the code... Anyone can tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

A very minor change change:  "[.]<-" to "[[.]]<-"

```
require(plyr)
year = c("1993", "2009")
for (i in 1:2) {
  temp <- subset(census.long, trt=="RIL" & dbh > 50 & date==year[i] )
  tab.res[[ year[i] ]] <- ddply(.data=temp, .(spcode), 
                 .fun=summarise, 
                 volume = sum(volume))
}
```

Assuming the `ddply` code is working individually which at the moment we have no way of testing. You could also have just done:

```
for (year in c("1993", "2009") ) {
  temp <- subset(census.long,trt=="RIL" & dbh > 50 & date==year)
  tab.res[[year]] <- ddply(.data=temp, .(spcode), 
                 .fun=summarise, 
                 volume = sum(volume))
}
```